# かつおぶし but かつをぶし

Tags: history, dialects, classical-japanese, kana-usage

While explaining [かつおぶし via the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katsuobushi).  There is a picture that has かつをぶし on a のれん:

[image]

In the dialect that I speak, we do make vocal substitutions, but we generally write with standard かな。If anyone has any insight to why を　was written instead of お, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't any kind of "dialect spelling" or "pronunciation spelling", but rather the **historical spelling**.  Historical spellings are the kana spellings from before the spelling reforms of the late 1800s up through the mid-1900s.  These older spellings often reflect the etymologies (word roots) of the terms.

For more about historical kana spellings, see these Wikipedia articles:

- [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/歴史的仮名遣](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_kana_orthography

In this case, the modern term かつお is from the older term かつを.  If we look at the monolingual Japanese dictionary aggregator site Kotobank and [their entry for 鰹【かつお】](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%B0%B9-464093), right at the top of the page we see the big kanji followed by the modern 読【よ】み or "reading", and the next line has a few items in grey boxes -- this includes `かつお〔かつを〕`, showing the modern kana spelling followed in the 〔brackets〕 by the historical kana spelling.

Although raw tuna is now a popular sushi ingredient, in older times, this fish was almost exclusively eaten only after it had been smoked and dried into hard bricks -- the better for easy transportation and long-term preservation.  Etymologically (in terms of word roots), researchers thus think this word is probably from 硬【かた】, the stem of adjective 硬【かた】い ("hard, not soft"), + 魚【うお】 ("fish"), older kana spelling (and older pronunciation) うを.  *kata* + *uwo* → *katauwo* → *katuwo* → modern *katsuo*.

For more about the etymology (derivation) of this word, see the entries at these monolingual Japanese dictionary sites:

- Nihon Jiten: http://www.nihonjiten.com/data/45561.html
- Gogen Allguide: http://gogen-allguide.com/ka/katsuo.html